# How to fix ''bytes' object has no attribute 'findAll''

Tags: object, attributes, byte, findall

I am trying to import videoId from a pickle folder and then print the description of the youtube video.and i am getting this error ='bytes' object has no attribute 'findAll'i want to extract the description with videoid and title in csv

```
cwd=os.getcwd()
parent_folder=os.path.join(cwd,'Data') pickle_out=open("C:/Users/india/Desktop/PARUL/Data/Pickle/vid_ids_dict.pickle","rb")
vid_id_dict=pickle.load(pickle_out)

dataset_folder=os.path.join(parent_folder,"Dataset")
if not os.path.exists(dataset_folder):
os.makedirs(dataset_folder)

csv_file_path= os.path.join(parent_folder,'main.csv')


base = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="
for keys, values in vid_id_dict.items():
for key in keys:
    query_dataset_folder=os.path.join(dataset_folder,key)

    if not os.path.exists(query_dataset_folder):
        os.makedirs(query_dataset_folder)

    for VidID in values:

        r = requests.get(base+VidID)
        soup = bs(r.text,'html.parser').encode("utf-8")
        name=VidID+".txt"
        save_description_link=os.path.join(query_dataset_folder,name)

        f= open(save_description_link,"a+")

        for title in soup.findAll('p', attrs={'id': 'eow-description'}):
            description=title.text.strip()
            f.write(description)
            print(description)
        f.close()

        for title in soup.findAll('span', attrs={'class': 'watch-title'}):
            vid_title= title.text.strip()
            print(vid_title)

        with open(csv_file_path, 'a+') as csvfile:
            fieldnames = ['Video id', 'Title','Description','Category']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            writer.writerow({'Video id': VidID, 'Title': vid_title, 'Description':description,'Category':key})
```

ERROR-
      AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
     in 
         35             f= open(save_description_link,"a+")
         36 
    ---> 37             for title in soup.findAll('p', attrs={'id': 'eow- 
                         description'}):
         38                 description=title.text.strip()
         39                 f.write(description)

AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'findAll'

Comment: Please add error text in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assume that you're using *requests* module for getting the http responses.

Just replace your code with:

```
r.encoding = 'utf-8'
soup = bs(req.content, 'html.parser')
```

Final Running code:

```
for keys, values in vid_id_dict.items():
for key in keys:
    query_dataset_folder=os.path.join(dataset_folder,key)

    if not os.path.exists(query_dataset_folder):
        os.makedirs(query_dataset_folder)

    for VidID in values:

        r = requests.get(base+VidID)
        r.encoding = 'utf-8'
        soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
        name=VidID+".txt"
        save_description_link=os.path.join(query_dataset_folder,name)

        f= open(save_description_link,"a+")

        for title in soup.findAll('p', attrs={'id': 'eow-description'}):
            description=title.text.strip()
            f.write(description)
            print(description)
        f.close()

        for title in soup.findAll('span', attrs={'class': 'watch-title'}):
            vid_title= title.text.strip()
            print(vid_title)

        with open(csv_file_path, 'a+') as csvfile:
            fieldnames = ['Video id', 'Title','Description','Category']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            writer.writerow({'Video id': VidID, 'Title': vid_title, 'Description':description,'Category':key})
```